# Using System.Text.Json to Serialize an IConfiguration back to Json

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, configuration, system.text.json

I'm storing some IConfiguration as json in my sqlserver db so I can then bind them to some already constructed classes in order to provide dynamic settings.

At some point I might change the binded properties new  at runtime and then update the db. The thing is that when i need to, the class might have more properties that aren't supposed to be bound and shouln't be serialized. I am therefore keeping the IConfiguration as a property of my class. Another reason why I'm using this approach is that I need to istantiate other children classes from the class that has loaded the configs, and save them to db when i do.

The thing is that when I serialize an IConfiguration i only get an empty json string like "{}".
I suppose i could do some shenanigans leveraging .AsEnumerable() but isn't there a better way?

My sample code would look somewhat like this

```
public class ConfigurableClass
{

    public int ChildrenCount { get; set; } = 1069;
    public bool IsFast { get; set; } = false;
    public bool HasChildren { get; set; } = false;

    public int Id { get; }

    public ConfigurableClass(int id) { Id = id; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    IEnumerable<string> configs = SqlConfigLoader.LoadConfig();

    foreach (var str in configs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parsing new Config:");

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        IConfiguration cfg = builder.AddJsonStream(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str)))
                .Build();

        var stepExample = new ConfigurableClass(9);

        cfg.Bind(stepExample);

        //do work with the class that might change the value of binded properties                   

        var updatedCfg = cfg;

        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(updatedCfg));

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Edit

I Also tried a diffent approach, by converting the IConfiguration to a nested dictionary like this

```
ublic static class IConfigurationExtensions
{
   public static Dictionary<string,object> ToNestedDicionary(this IConfiguration configuration)
   {
       var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
       var children = configuration.GetChildren();
       if (children.Any()) 
           foreach (var child in children)
               result.Add(child.Key, child.ToNestedDicionary());
       else 
           if(configuration is IConfigurationSection section)
               result.Add(section.Key, section.Get(typeof(object)));

       return result;
   }        
}
```

But I lose the implicit type behind a given JsonElement:

if i serialize the resulting dictionary i get thing like "Property": "True" instead of "Property" : true

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## First, the why

Attempting to serialize the `IConfiguration` this way is not going to work how you want it to. Let's explore why.

### Serializing Interfaces

*Part* of the reason you get no properties is because the generic type argument to `Serialize` is `IConfiguration`. In other words you are calling:

```
JsonSerializer.Serialize<IConfiguration>(updatedCfg)
```

When System.Text.Json serializes using a generic parameter it only (by default without any custom converters) serializes the public properties of that interface. In this case `IConfiguration` has no public properties (other than an indexer) so your output is empty json.

#### Using runtime-type information

Now, *in general* to get around this you would use the [non-generic overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serialize?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_Serialize_System_Object_System_Type_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_) and pass the type. For example that would look like:

```
JsonSerializer.Serialize(updatedCfg, updatedCfg.GetType());
```

Or alternatively by using `object` as the type parameter:

```
JsonSerializer.Serialize<object>(updatedCfg);
```

System.Text.Json will then use the *runtime type* information in order to determine what properties to serialize.

### The `ConfigurationRoot`

Now the second part of your problem is that this is unfortunately still not going to work due to how the configuration system is designed. The [`ConfigurationRoot`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e3ffd343ad5bd3a999cb9515f59e6e7a777b2c34/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/src/ConfigurationRoot.cs#L16) class (the result of `Build`) can aggregate many configuration sources. The data is stored individually within (or even external to) each provider. When you request a value from the configuration it loops through each provider in order to locate a match.

All of this to say that the concrete/runtime type of your `IConfiguration` object will still not have the public properties you desire to serialize. In fact, passing the runtime type in this case will do **worse** than mimic the behavior of the interface as it will attempt to serialize the only public property of that type ([`ConfigurationRoot.Providers`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e3ffd343ad5bd3a999cb9515f59e6e7a777b2c34/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/src/ConfigurationRoot.cs#L45)). This will give you a list of *serialized providers*, each typed as [`IConfigurationProvider`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e3ffd343ad5bd3a999cb9515f59e6e7a777b2c34/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions/src/IConfigurationProvider.cs) and having zero public properties.

## A potential solution

Since you are attempt to serialize the configuration that you are ultimately binding to an object, a workaround would be to re-serialize *that* object instead:

```
var stepExample = new ConfigurableClass(9);
cfg.Bind(stepExample);
var json1 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(stepExample, stepExample.GetType());
// or with the generic version which will work here
var json2 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(stepExample);
```

## An alternative solution - `AsEnumerable`

`IConfiguration` is ultimately a collection of key value pairs. We can make use of the [`AsEnumerable`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e3ffd343ad5bd3a999cb9515f59e6e7a777b2c34/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions/src/ConfigurationExtensions.cs#L53) extension method to create a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` out of the entire configuration. This can later be deserialized and passed to something like  `AddInMemoryCollection`

You'll need the [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions/) (which is likely already transitively referenced) and the following `using` directive:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
```

And then you can create a list of all the values (with keys in `Section:Key` format)

```
var configAsList = cfg.AsEnumerable().ToList();
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(configAsList);
```

Or you can use `ToDictionary` and serialize that instead.

```
var configAsDict = cfg.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value);
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(configAsDict);
```

Both formats will work with `AddInMemoryCollection` as that only requires an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` (which both types are). However, you will likely need the Dictionary format if you wish to use `AddJsonFile/Stream` as I don't *think* those support an array of key/value pairs.

## Strings, strings and nothing but strings

You seem to be under the impression that `IConfiguration` objects are storing `int`s, `bool`s, etc. (for example) corresponding to the JSON Element type. This is incorrect. All data within an `IConfiguration` is stored in **stringified form**. The base Configuration Provider classes all expect an `IDictionary<string, string>` filled with data. Even the JSON Configuration Providers [perform an explicit `ToString`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e3ffd343ad5bd3a999cb9515f59e6e7a777b2c34/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/src/JsonConfigurationFileParser.cs#L83) on the values.

The *stringyly-typed* values are turned into **strongly-typed** ones when you call `Bind`, `Get<>` or `GetValue<>`. These make use of the configuration *binder* which in turn uses registered `TypeConverters` and well know string parsing methods. But under the covers everything is still a string. This means it doesn't matter if your json file has a string property with value `"True"` or a boolean property with value `true`. The binder will appropriately convert the value when mapping to a `boolean` property.

Using the above dictionary serializing method will work as intended.

Comment: the thing is that I wanted to leverage IConfig dynamism because the object is actually a derived class that might have some properties or not, I use the IConfiguration inside a Factory Class that determines the correct derived class  and, after invoking the correct constructor, proceedes to bind the custom properties

Comment: IConfiguration seemed a good tool to do so, this way a custom derived class could have both its parsed settings and the raw IConfiguration. The objective is for every instance to be loaded correcly, have it mutate and be saved back to db

Comment: I guess our solutions have that common flaw (I updated my post), maybe I should try a different approach leveraging dynamic instead of a IConfiguration...

Comment: In response to your comment on your edit, IConfiguration has no concept of ints/bools. Everything is a string *until* it's bound to a container of the appropriate type. There's no reason that serializing to a dictionary and then back again wouldn't work because when it's rebound to your object the correct type converters will kick in. Whatever the json element's type is doesn't matter. It's **always** a string in the underlying configuration objects. It's calling `Bind`, `Get<>`, `GetValue<>` that have logic in them to perform conversions. true.ToString is "True" it will round-trip correctly

Comment: And just to prove it, look at this line from the JSON file provider. This is part of a routine that returns a **`Dictionary<string, string>`** as required by the configuration infrastructure https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e3ffd343ad5bd3a999cb9515f59e6e7a777b2c34/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/src/JsonConfigurationFileParser.cs#L83 you'll see it forcibly calls ToString on all the values you that you *believe* it preserves. It doesn't! The "dynamism" you refer to is part of the binder used to translate configs and not the configuration itself. My answer works :)

Answer (score 4):

just ran into a similar requirement. Serializing `IConfiguration` to send over a bus. Here's what I came up with

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Memory;

namespace A6k
{
    public class ConfigurationConverter : JsonConverter<IConfiguration>
    {
        public override IConfiguration Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            var root = new ConfigurationRoot(new List<IConfigurationProvider>(new[] { new MemoryConfigurationProvider(new MemoryConfigurationSource()) }));

            var pathParts = new Stack<string>();
            string currentProperty = null;
            string currentPath = null;
            while (reader.Read() && (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndObject || pathParts.Count > 0))
            {
                switch (reader.TokenType)
                {
                    case JsonTokenType.PropertyName:
                        currentProperty = reader.GetString();
                        break;
                    case JsonTokenType.String:
                        if (pathParts.Count == 0)
                            root[currentProperty] = reader.GetString();
                        else
                            root[ConfigurationPath.Combine(currentPath, currentProperty)] = reader.GetString();
                        break;
                    case JsonTokenType.StartObject:
                        pathParts.Push(currentProperty);
                        currentPath = ConfigurationPath.Combine(pathParts);
                        break;
                    case JsonTokenType.EndObject:
                        pathParts.Pop();
                        currentPath = ConfigurationPath.Combine(pathParts);
                        break;
                }
            }
            return root;
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IConfiguration value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (value is IConfigurationSection section)
            {
                if (section.Value is null)
                    writer.WriteStartObject(section.Key);
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteString(section.Key, section.Value);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
                writer.WriteStartObject();

            foreach (var child in value.GetChildren())
                Write(writer, child, options);

            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

It just uses a single memory config provider when deserializing. But the resulting `IConfiguration` behaves the same way as the sent instance.

Just add this as a converter to your serialization:

```cs
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(configuration, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
  Converters = { new ConfigurationConverter() },
  WriteIndented = true
});
```

or add as an attribute on a property

```cs
public class MyThing
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ConfigurationConverter))]
    public IConfiguration Config { get; set; }
}
```

Good luck!